# Eigen equivalent of Matlab's sum(A)?

Tags: c++, eigen, eigen3

How can I get the row vector, each value of which is the sum of each column of a 2D `Array` in Eigen?

I want the equivalent of the Matlab  `sum` function, i.e.

```
>> x = [1,2,3;4,5,6]

x =

     1.0000e+000     2.0000e+000     3.0000e+000
     4.0000e+000     5.0000e+000     6.0000e+000

>> sum (x)

ans =

     5.0000e+000     7.0000e+000     9.0000e+000
```

can I use `colwise` to do this somehow?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `m.colwise().sum()`.

See at **Combining partial reductions with other operations** section [here](https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/group__TutorialReductionsVisitorsBroadcasting.html).